Problemas de importación de módulos de Google Drive a Colab
les escribo porque estoy presentando problemas para importar un modulo que cree a google Colab.Pasa que cuando le doy a Abrir Cuaderno --> Subir --> Explorar y selecciono el archivo (que obviamente esta en formato .py) Colab me arroja el siguiente error:
Unexpected token 'd', "    def prom(A"... is not valid JSON
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'd', "    def prom(A"... is not valid JSON
   at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
   at xa.program_ (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/0b6aa537804ea9c561616830954cf927/external_binary_l10n__es.js:3655:261)
   at za (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/0b6aa537804ea9c561616830954cf927/external_binary_l10n__es.js:16:57)
   at xa.next_ (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/0b6aa537804ea9c561616830954cf927/external_binary_l10n__es.js:14:195)
   at kaa.next (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/0b6aa537804ea9c561616830954cf927/external_binary_l10n__es.js:17:48)
   at b (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/0b6aa537804ea9c561616830954cf927/external_binary_l10n__es.js:17:309)

No se porque no me deja importar el archivo que será un modulo. El código que contiene mi archivo a importar son estas funciones:
    def prom(A):
        n=len(A);
        S=0;
        for k in range(n):
           S=S+A[k];
        S=S/n;
        return S

    def suma(a,b):
        x=a+b;
        return x

    def resta(a,b):
        x=a-b;
        return x

    def pot(a,b):
        x=a**b;
        return x

De verdad agradecería mucho su ayuda, estoy trabado en esto, ya consulté en Google y no me aparece ningún resultado, dice que hay un error, que no se han encontrado resultados en la búsqueda. No sé que hacer

En Codelab solo podes abrir archivos .ipynb en los cuales su contenido está en formato JSON. Más info

Colab ejecuta Notebooks de Jupyter/IPython y ese menú que estás usando es para importar un notebook, archivos con extensión .ipynb, pero que son simples JSON, de ahí el error al intentar parsearlo.
Si lo que quieres es subir un módulo normal de Python para poder importarlo en el Notebook de colab, puedes hacerlo de varias formas, dos de las más comunes y simples son:
Desde cualquier ubicación local en tu dispositivo

Clic en el icono con una carpeta en la barra lateral izquierda:



Clic en "Subir al almacenamiento de sesión"



En el diálogo de selección de archivos que se abrirá, seleccionas el archivo de interés y aceptas.

Con ello podrás importar el archivo y usar sus funciones en el notebook sin problemas o ejecutarlo en una celda con %run nombre_del_modulo.py.
Ten en cuenta que el archivo solo estará disponible mientras exista ese entorno de ejecución, puedes editarlo desde Colab, pero no se guardará para futuras sesiones.
Desde Google Drive
Si tienes el archivo en tu Google Drive también puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Haz clic en el mismo icono "Archivos" de la barra lateral izquierda mencionado antes.

Clic en el icono "Montar Drive"



Una vez montado (tendrás que aceptar un popup del tipo "Desea permitir el acceso a drive..." y configurar los permisos de Drive de ser necesario) podrás importar los módulos igual que antes:

Haz clic en la imagen para verla más detalladamente, en ella se muestra el disco de Drive montado y la estructura de archivos del mismo, el módulo abierto en un editor y como se importa en una celda del Notebook a modo de muestra. Recuerda que debes adaptar el import a la ruta adecuada en tu caso concreto (punto de montaje, nombre del disco, subcarpetas y nombre del archivo)):
Otra opción es montar Drive desde el propio Notebook en una celda mediante código directamente:
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/ruta/a/punto/de/montaje/deseado')

Una vez montado el proceso de importación y demás es igual que antes.

Si quieres usar el archivo directamente tendrás que convertirlo en un Notebook previamente o abrir uno nuevo en colab y pegar su contenido en una celda...
